# Stick Footer to Bottom of Page without (unnecessary) scroll bars

Tags: html, css

***EDIT 2:***

There was an error in my code that was causing the footer to not stick to the bottom of the page. My code looked something like this:

```
<div id="footer">
 <div id="copyright-bg" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="twelvecol">
    <p class="copyright-text">Lorum Ipsum</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I removed `<div id="footer">` and moved those CSS properties to `id="copyright-bg"` and it then began to stick properly to the bottom. But now there has risen another issue! I now have unnecessary scroll bars! [Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVKq3/1/) that has the barest of code to attempt to figure what is going on. I thought it could be the gradient but when I changed the code to a solid background the scroll bars still appeared.

Note: I have tested in Chrome and Firefox.

***EDIT:***

I have attempted to use the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) per instructions on the [website](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

I assume there is a conflict in my CSS(?) [here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PekEf/3/) of the page.

I have also attempted what [this website suggested](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) and while it technically works it creates scrollbars! I would like to avoid that if possible.

***Original Question***

I am working on a page and if the page does not have much content (IE no scroll bars for the page) I am left with a black bar below my copyright container.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Note: Where you see the word `Done` is the bottom of my browser, an arrow is pointing to the black bar.

I have attempted a few things to remove the bar. When I add `height: 100%;` to the body tag it will take my background gradient and it will reach to the bottom of the page but again that doesn't look good. I then attempted to add `height: 100%` to the copyright container. That caused the gray area to stretch way down and cause excessive empty space and scrollbars. I have attempted to position the element absolutely but that causes several other issues and would prefer to avoid positioning absolutely.

How do I remove the black bar? (Preferably with just CSS but will accept an answer that uses jQuery/Javascript)

***CODE***:

*HTML:*

```
<!-- Body Content Is Here -->
<div id="copyright-bg" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="twelvecol">
    <p class="copyright-text">Ipsum</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
html, body{
font-size:1em;
font-family: "ff-dagny-web-pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height:1.438em;
color:#222;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 100%);
    /* Vendor Specific Background Gradients... */
}

#copyright-bg{
margin-top:1.875em;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666666;
    border-top: 5px solid #E31836;
padding:1.250em;
}

.container {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

.row .twelvecol {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
 }
```

Comment: padding:1.250em? May I ask why you are having an elastic layout when all browsers support zoom?

Comment: @Jawad - The page I am building is responsive design based for multiple monitor sizes and mobile platforms.

Comment: Right. My bad. Any possibility of a Fiddle?

Comment: You may on the other hand need a sticky footer. - http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: @Jawad - The sticky footer did not work, not sure why. I created a fiddle, see edit to question (at top).

Comment: If you don't want the gradient to expand to fill the full height it shouldn't be attached to the `body` but should be given an element that is appropriately sized.  What are you looking to take the place of the present black bar?  If you want gray then that should be the background of the body or of another container element with a `min-height` of 100%;

Comment: I don't understand how all of these hackish workarounds could possibly be preferred over absolute positioning when it was made for exactly this type of thing.  It brings _issues_ that result in better understanding how positioning works; fighting it just brings layers of complexity and obfuscation.

Comment: @MattWhipple - First Comment: I want the footer at the bottom with the background gradient filling the empty space in between. Second Comment: When I position absolutely it causes another whole set of problems but I might attempt to fix those before continuing with this issue.

Comment: The scrollbars possibly appear due to your adding of border and padding to the fotter. Just increase the negative margin to compenstate for it. margin-top: -35px; /* negative value of footer height */ - http://jsfiddle.net/aVKq3/27/

Comment: does the example with JS make it stay even when re sized???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have tried multiple solutions (like [Ryan Fait's footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) or the <s>[CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)</s> (this link is broken, [see this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449156/stick-footer-to-bottom-of-page-without-unnecessary-scroll-bars)), which is my favorite) then I would bet that you have a bigger problem than face value.  Those two examples have proven the test of time and yet still remain the most commonly used methods for creating a footer which sticks to the bottom of the page.  While I'm not bashing your code, I would suggest that maybe you redo the page you're creating from scratch and have the first implementation be the sticky footer.  From there you should just be able to copy and paste over your visual styles and if it screws up again then you know your culprit line of code.

**EDIT:**

I needed to edit your code a bit because the lack of indentation made it difficult to read.  [Here's the new jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PekEf/7/)  What I did change were a few things.  Here's the additions to the top of your CSS code:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 
html, body {height: 100%;}

#content-wrap {min-height: 100%;}
```

Those lines are 100% necessary to make your code work.  Not only do you need to do a wildcard (`*`) reset on all elements, but you also need to tell the document (`html`) and the body (`body`) to take up the full height of the screen.  I don't remember if it was in your original CSS, but `#content-wrap` should have a `min-height` of 100% as well.

After searching through, I realize your footer isn't actually 180px in height, but rather 100px in height.  [Here's the final jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PekEf/8/)  And also, here's the final code to make the footer stick:

```
#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 100px;
    clear:both;}
```

You should see now that when you apply this code, the footer sticks to the bottom (and does so without duct tape).  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am using a [1140 Grid System](http://cssgrid.net/) which is what my code is based. I believe it may be causing the issue.

Comment: That's likely the case.  I'd still suggest however starting from scratch with the 1140 grid a a CSS sticky footer and working back to where you are from there.

Comment: I started to re-write my code and solved one issue but have another now! See my edit above to see whats going on now. (Note: It turned out not to be related to the 1140 grid system.)

Comment: @Lynda, I edited my code to reflect your comments.  Take a look!

Comment: * {margin:0;padding:0;} ! Universal reset?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still seem to have scroll bars but I believe this is in my code somewhere, I will find it and nail it down eventually. Luckily (or hopefully) most of the pages will have at least some content and not be to short except maybe on large monitors.

Comment: @Jawad: Yep, it's required for the CSS sticky footer.  It's debatable, but depending on your website, it's not a bad idea.  I use a reset all the time to ensure cross-browser uniformity.

@Lynda: The scroll bars can be eliminated by hiding the overflow on the `html` and `body`: 'overflow-x: hidden;' for horizontal scrollbars and 'overflow-y: hidden' for vertical scroll bars.

Comment: @Lynda: did fixing the negative margin not slove the scollbar problem?

Comment: if overflow: hidden is set on html & body elements, no scrollbars will appear even if the content increases!

Comment: @Jawad - Yes and No. I could get the footer to move up but at the point the scroll bars would disappear the background would start to show. I have to work with it more. - As for your second comment, while that is true I do not want to hide any elements that expand past page view.

Comment: @Jawad: Not every website is the same, and applying a CSS reset is up to the choice of a developer.  It depends on the website and your needs, there's no universal answer.  If it works for Lynda, then it's the correct answer.  Not to mention, it's also clearly in the code of the CSS sticky footer.  If you care that much about it then you may replace the CSS reset with whatever you so choose instead.

Answer (score 2):

Majority of the sticky footer codes seem to cause issues with my page. To work around this issue I am using the following code:

***HTML***

```
<body>
 <div id="page-content">
   <header> 
     <!-- Header Content Goes Here --> 
   </header> 

     <!-- Page Content Goes Here --> 

   <footer>
     <!-- Footer Content Goes Here --> 
   </footer>

 </div>
</body>
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {
   var height = $(window).height() - ($("header").outerHeight() + $("footer").outerHeight() );
 $("#page-content").css("min-height",height+"px");
});
```

What this does is calculate the height of the page and set a minimum height for the page, thus sticking the footer to the bottom. It works beautifully.

Note: I am using HTML5.